# FUELPHP Ajax request without jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, fuelphp

I have looked everywhere, I found, that FUELPHP not handle Ajax requests, native and easily, as does RubyOnRails for example.

There must be done manually through jquery, unless I'm missing something I see is this: you have to use preventDefault () for the submit event of the form to create a post, product or whatever, and use the $ function post () to send the relevant parameters, which I think is ridiculous for a framework that claims to be based on the best ideas from other frameworks.

Please tell me if I'm wrong, I like FUELPHP, and I'm thinking about choosing it as PHP framework, but I want to be clear about this.

Comment: Some do not want to prevent default handling of events and since that is written into JavaScript the developers at jQuery decided not to re-invent the wheel, so to speak. How do you think it should work?

Comment: You might be getting a bit confused here. FuelPHP is a PHP framework, it runs on the server and has nothing to do with JavaScript other than serving it to the browser. I don't know of any framework in the PHP world that mimics RoR's ajaxy form handling.

Answer (score 1):

why not you can handle ajax in fuelphp like this.

.01. create ajax request in your view or public/assets/ create javascript file,

```
    <script>     $('.login').on('click',function(){
                      $.ajax({
                    xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                            alert("loading");
                            }, false);
                            return xhr;
                    },
                            url: "<?php echo \Uri::create('auth/login'); ?>",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: 'json'
                            data: {'username':$('#username').val(), 'password':$('#password').val()},
                            success: function (data) {
                            alert(data.status);
                            },
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("error");
                            }
                    });

});

        </script>
```

.02. after that you can handle post data in classes/controller/ create auth.php and login method like this,

```
<?php

class Controller_Auth extends \Controller_Template {

    function action_login() {
        if (\Input::is_ajax()) {
            if (\Input::param('username') and \Input::param('password')) {
                $username = \Input::param('username');
                $password = md5(\Input::param('password'));
                //check password and username or anything
                $msg = 'fail';
                return json_encode(array('status' => $msg));
            }
        }
        ...
    }

}
?>
```

you can handle data like this. i think you got something. and this is helpful.